# form-control no aplica formato

Tags: bootstrap, formularios, bootstrap-4

Por algún motivo, siguiendo un tutorial al pie de la letra e incluso copiando y pegando código no consigo que form-control funcione.
Ya intenté escribiendolo en el HTML como .form-control y tampoco funciona, estoy usando bootstrap-4.4.1-dist, copié y pegué las carpetas de bootstrap (css y js) dentro de la carpeta de mi proyecto.
Dejo una imagen de como se ve en el navegador.
Google chrome no funciona en mi PC (crashea al abrir y reinstalarlo no sirvió de nada) por lo que solo puedo visualizar en mozilla y edge, en ambos se ve mal.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flogin/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ibody">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Contactenos</h1>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" name="fcontacto" id="fcontacto" action="./">
            <label>Tu nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
            <label> Tu email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
            <label> Asunto:</label>
            <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" class="form-control">
            <label> Tu Mensaje:</label>
            <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </form>


    </div>
</body>

</html>

  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.ibody {
    background-color: #ecf0f3;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 500px;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding: 16px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Navegador]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien muestra la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) Bootstrap, en su página oficial, para hacer uso de todos los componentes de este framework, se debe de hacer referencia a los archivos que este posee:

Para hacer referencia a CSS, se debe se colocar lo siguiente en el `head` de tu archivo html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Y los archivos JS, deben de ir de preferencia al final del template, antes de terminar el `body`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

O de otra manera puedes descargar los archivos, como menciona en [este apartado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/) de la página oficial, en la misma especifica los pasos a seguir para que todos los componentes descargados funcionen correctamente.

Resultado final:

```css
* {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }

        .ibody {
            background-color: #ecf0f3;
            margin: 30px auto;
            width: 500px;
        }

        .jumbotron {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .jumbotron h1 {
            font-size: 26px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flogin/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ibody">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Contactenos</h1>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" name="fcontacto" id="fcontacto" action="./">
            <label>Tu nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
            <label> Tu email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
            <label> Asunto:</label>
            <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" class="form-control">
            <label> Tu Mensaje:</label>
            <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </form>


    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchísimas gracias, lo que me llama la atención es que en el tutorial no mencionan el código que hace referencia al CSS y aún así funciona, cambió eso a medida que se actualizó Bootstrap? Por que es un tutorial viejo pero el mas reciente que encontré en YT :s

Comment: Si descargo los archivos, quizás hizo referencia al css de bootstrap, mediante `"flogin/css/bootstrap.css"` ya que ahí se encontraban los archivos correspondientes